# XML parser won't work

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing

I'm trying to load an XML feed into my app i'm using an [XML parser framework from Github.](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML)
In my ViewDidload i placed

```
[self Loadit];
```

and

```
- (void)Loadit {

    RXMLElement *LoadFile = [RXMLElement elementFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];

    [LoadFile iterate:@"Name" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *element) {
        NSString *name = [element attribute:@"User"];
        NSLog(@"APP NAME: %@", name);
    }];

    NSLog(@"Done");

}
```

But i don't know if i'm stupid  but it's not call the function

```
[LoadFile iterate:@"Name" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *element) {
        NSString *name = [element attribute:@"User"];
        NSLog(@"APP NAME: %@", name);
    }];
```

Does anyone know why? The Nslog doens't appear in my logs in xCode

```
        NSLog(@"APP NAME: %@", name);
```

Comment: Do you get `NSLog(@"Done")`? The other `NSLog` is inside of a block so that might be your problem.

Comment: @Dustin Yes i'm getting the NSLog 'Done'! How can i request the block?

Comment: Are you checked your XML Format or link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure that the parameter "Name" (in this method - `[LoadFile iterate:@"Name" usingBlock:^(RXMLElement *element)`)is  present in your XML and is as exactly as in XML (I mean to say check case sensitiveness).